# If I use UIWebview in my app, will app store reject it since it has been officially deprecated?

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I made an AR app which embedded the UIWebView to display web content on an SCNPlane. I can not use the WKWebView because it does not work well with AR. On the contrary, UIWebView works nice. 
If I upload my app into the app store, will my app get rejected?

Also, I notice that on the UIWebView's official document page, there is an certain alert says "An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its Info.plist file the usage description keys for the types of data it needs to access or it will crash." Do i need to add certain specific description key for the UIWebView?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, they won’t reject you. No, you don’t have to provide any kind of information about UIWebView

Comment: Thanks! I am going to upload my app to the app store and I was sort of worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Deprecated doesn't mean unavailable or disallowed; otherwise those methods would simply be removed from the API.Deprecation is a way of letting you know that you should start transitioning your existing codebase.

Deprecated methods may be more primitive and dangerous than newer versions, may not take into account all current OS features.

Comment: Thanks for your help!